Limited pet snack selection in bazaar
This past week (c. 11/11/24) the Bazaar Revamp was implemented, allowing filters to be used when buying and selling in the bazaar, and offering other enhancements.
However, since it was implemented, I have been unable to purchase the pet snacks I regularly buy.  Instead of pages of snacks being available for purchase, I have seen at most one page, usually only a few snacks, and sometimes one or even none.  I have checked twice a day for the last week.
Is this a bug with the update?  Am I not understanding how to access snacks with the new filters?
EDIT: As of today (11/20/24) I am seeing the regular 20+ pages of snacks available in the bazaar.  Some of the prices for my habitual snacks are high, but I imagine there is a lot of pent-up demand at this point.

This is very likely a bug, seeing your complaint pops up elsewhere, like here on Reddit:

There are things which were never scarce that are now completely out of stock (lower value pet snacks used in recipes, non rare TCs).


At the time of writing this there are zero pet snacks of any kind in the bazaar, this has to be a bug.

Judging by the upvotes and similar messages and threads, a lot of other users are experiencing this.
In Wizard101's Discord, a bug report has been filed:

New Bazaar not stocking sold Reagents & Snacks
tried selling a couple not here and it just ate them. seems to be bugged.

A possible explanation is offered directly underneath (my emphasis):

I recall Artie ["GraniteHeart" Rogers, one of the devs] considering adding a randomized delay to when items are posted in the bazaar after they’re sold. Perhaps they went through with it, but I haven’t seen any dev messages confirming that.

But at this point, the problem has not been fixed or explained.
